# Acord Standard for Insurance. Has anybody dealt with this mess?

Tags: c#, wcf, xsd

We need to implement a WCF Webservice using the [ACORD Standard](http://www.acord.org/standards/downloads/Pages/PCSSpecsPublic.aspx).

However, I don't know where to start with this since this standard is HUMONGOUS and very convoluted. A total chaos to my eyes.

I am trying to use WSCF.Blue to extract the classes from the multiple XSD I have but so far all I get is a bunch of crap: A .cs file with 50,000+ lines of code that freezes my VS2010 all the time.

Has anybody walked already thru the Valley of Death (ACORD Standard) and made it? I really would appreciate some help.

Comment: What _specific_ help do you need? I recommend editing to ask a particular question, since this is too general atm - and is the kind of thing that normally gets closed.

Comment: The Project that generates the code file from the XSD need not be in the same project that uses it (should not, likely) and needs not even be part of the same Solution (e.g. it can be a referenced library) ... this will alleviate the issue of freezing, even if it doesn't necessarily fix anything else :) Consider cleaning up the language in the post to make the question more objective.

Comment: I worked with format of Transaction($) files once which is, after a quick look at your link, pretty much the same as you'll encounter. My advise, don't fight the system. It'll be ugly.It'll be a mess. You'll do it once and you'll never look back after. Don't try to make anything fancy and just make it work. Those days were my worst days as a programmer. Good luck !

Comment: @asawyer - the OP obviously is in dire need or they wouldn't have posted what is clearly a cry for help. Rubbing their faces in it further by indicating you have a solution which you are unwilling to share is not only unhelpful but downright *daggy*. At least give the OP some high level pointers.

Comment: @hugh You are correct. Tony I apologize. I had only meant to answer the "has anyone made it bit" but I do see Hugh's point, and my comment was not constructive.

Comment: If your API implements XML and it's open to other organizations don't forget to consider versioning using namespaces. They may only implement one version of the standard. If your API doesn't support many versions it may turn away customers. XML namespaces let one API endpoint support all versions of ACORD

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are heading down the right path but are lost in the forest.
The ACORD Standard is huge and intentionally so, as it provides support for hundreds of different messages.  Just as you do not download all of Wikipedia to get just a few articles, you do not need all of the classes in the ACORD Standard to support an implementation of a few messages.  If you know what messages you need to support then you can generate a subset of the full XSD that will be quite manageable.

As mentioned in Hugh’s response, for any one message only a fraction of the full XSD is used.  How you go about doing that will depend on the specifics of your project.  If you are looking for ideas on how generate a subset of the full XSD try reaching out to the ACORD staff for help at [PCS@acord.org](http://acord.org/about/contacts/Pages/Inquiries.aspx).  They should be able to offer you some help in getting started.

Comment: "Just as you do not download all of Wikipedia to get just a few articles, you do not need all of the classes in the ACORD Standard to support an implementation of a few messages." Very nicely said. This is often termed "Schema Slicing".  Acord also offers members a number of premade "transactions" which are already sliced into smaller schemas.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a ACORD to c# class library converter which was then used in several large commercial insurance products.  It featured a very nice mapping of all of the ACORD XML into nice concise, extendable C# classes.  So I know from whence you come!

Once you dig into it its not so bad, but I maintain the average coder will not 'get it' for about 3-4 months if they work at it full time (assuming anything but inquiry style messages).  The real problem comes when trying to do mapping from a backend database and to/from another ACORD WS.  All of the carriers, vendors, and agencies have custom rules.

My best suggestion is to find working code examples (I have tons if you need them) and maybe even a vendor or carrier who will let you hook up to a ACORD ws in a test environment.

Comment: nice work by any means. Can you please share your ACORD2C# library ?

Answer (score 2):

I have worked with the Accord PCS exposure reporting standards and yes it was a nightmare. I have also worked with other large standards like FPML and SportsML.

You need to work out exactly which types from the schema that are needed. How you do this is up to you, but VS schema viewer should be able to handle it. If not try XmlSpy or just go through it by hand if you have to. Make sure you have a good BA to hand...

Chances are you will find that you can meet your requirements by using around 1% of the types available in the standard.

What you'll probably find is that you can express the core objects with a very minimal set of values, as most nodes will be `minOccurs=0` or `nillable`.

Then you can use the /element switch on xsd.exe to generate the code for just the types you need.

As one commenter says there is no easy pill to swallow here. The irony is that standards are supposed to make everyone's lives easier.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to read/write ACORD documents using .NET, I just stumbled across the "IVC Software Factory for ACORD Standards" on CodePlex at http://ivc.codeplex.com.

From the limited documentation it appears as if this library can convert objects to ACORD XML documents, and vice-versa. The source code comes with different "providers" i.e. different ACORD transaction types, like 103 or 121.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not creating a model for the entire standard.  One could just pass XML and not serialize into a model but instead load it into XDocument/XElement and use Linq to query it and update the DOM using Linq to Xml.   So, one is not loading the XML to a strongly typed model, but just loading the XML.  There is no model, just an XML document.

From there, one can pick the data off of the XML as needed.

Using this approach, the code will be ugly and have little context since XElements will be passed everywhere, and there will be tons of magic strings of XPaths to query and define elements, but it can work. Also, everything is a string so there will be utility conversion methods to convert to numbers, date times, etc.

From my prospective, I have modeled part of the Acord into an object model using the XmlSerializer but it's well over 500 classes.  The model was not tooled from XSD or other, but crafted manually and took some time.  Tooling will produce monster unusable classes (as you have mentioned) and/or flat out crash.  As an example, I tried to load the XSD into Stylus Studio and it crashed several times.

So, your best bet if your strapped for time is loading into an XDocument as opposed to trying to map out everything in a model.  I know that sucks but Acord in general is basically a huge data hot mess.